# PostgreSQL: query slow, planner estimates 0.01-0.1 of actual results

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

I will preface this by saying I'm not well-versed in SQL. I mainly work with ORMs, and this recent headache has brought me to dive into the world of queries, planners, etc..

A very common query is behaving weirdly on my website. I have tried various techniques to solve it but nothing is really helping, except narrowing down the `released_date` field from 30 days to 7 days. However, from my understanding the tables we're talking about aren't very big and PostgreSQL should satisfy my query in acceptable times.

(Notice: the query below actually queries for a 60 day range - this is because I need 30 days forward and 30 days back, for our purposes, this is a 60 day query.)

**Some statistics:**

`core_releasegroup` row count: 3,240,568

`core_artist` row count: 287,699

`core_subscription` row count: 1,803,960

**Relationships:**

Each `ReleaseGroup` has M2M with `Artist`, each `Artist` has M2M with `UserProfile` through `Subscription`. I'm using Django which auto-creates indices on foreign-keys, etc..

**Unique characteristics of database:**

Most music releases have a `release_date` that corresponds to a Friday, because that's the day most artists prefer to release their music. (Sidenote: could any benefits be made from converting the `date` field to a `timestamp` and just generating a random hour for each release?)

**Here's the query:**

```sql
SELECT "core_releasegroup"."id", "core_releasegroup"."title", "core_releasegroup"."type", "core_releasegroup"."release_date", "core_releasegroup"."applemusic_id", "core_releasegroup"."applemusic_image", "core_releasegroup"."geo_apple_music_link", "core_releasegroup"."amazon_aff_link", "core_releasegroup"."is_explicit", "core_releasegroup"."spotify_id", "core_releasegroup"."spotify_link" 
FROM "core_releasegroup" 
INNER JOIN "core_artist_release_groups" 
ON ("core_releasegroup"."id" = "core_artist_release_groups"."releasegroup_id") 
WHERE ("core_artist_release_groups"."artist_id" 
IN 
(SELECT U0."artist_id" FROM "core_subscription" U0 WHERE U0."profile_id" = 1) 
AND "core_releasegroup"."type" IN ('Album', 'Single', 'EP', 'Live', 'Compilation', 'Remix', 'Other') 
AND "core_releasegroup"."release_date" BETWEEN '2020-08-20'::date AND '2020-10-20'::date);
```

**Here's the initial table schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE public.core_releasegroup (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    modified_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    title character varying(560) NOT NULL,
    type character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    release_date date,
    applemusic_id character varying(512),
    applemusic_image character varying(512),
    applemusic_link character varying(512),
    spotify_id character varying(512),
    spotify_image character varying(512),
    spotify_link character varying(512),
    is_explicit boolean NOT NULL,
    spotify_last_refresh timestamp with time zone,
    spotify_next_refresh timestamp with time zone,
    geo_apple_music_link character varying(512),
    amazon_aff_link character varying(620)
);
```

**indices:**

```sql
mb_12=# SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'core_releasegroup';
```

Artist table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.core_artist (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    modified_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    name character varying(560) NOT NULL,
    applemusic_id character varying(512) NOT NULL,
    itunes_link character varying(512),
    spotify_id character varying(512),
    spotify_image character varying(512),
    spotify_link character varying(512),
    last_refreshed timestamp with time zone,
    applemusic_image character varying(512),
    spotify_last_refresh timestamp with time zone,
    spotify_resolve_manually boolean NOT NULL,
    last_itunes_refresh timestamp with time zone,
    next_itunes_refresh timestamp with time zone
);
```

indices:

```
 schemaname |  tablename  |                indexname                | tablespace |                                                          indexdef
------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | core_artist | core_artist_applemusic_id_009c5120_uniq |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_artist_applemusic_id_009c5120_uniq ON public.core_artist USING btree (applemusic_id)
 public     | core_artist | core_artist_pkey                        |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_artist_pkey ON public.core_artist USING btree (id)
 public     | core_artist | core_artist_applemusic_id_009c5120_like |            | CREATE INDEX core_artist_applemusic_id_009c5120_like ON public.core_artist USING btree (applemusic_id varchar_pattern_ops)
 public     | core_artist | core_artist_last_refreshed_2480a006     |            | CREATE INDEX core_artist_last_refreshed_2480a006 ON public.core_artist USING btree (last_refreshed)
```

Artist-ReleaseGroup:

```
     Column      |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                        Default                         | Storage | Stats target | Description
-----------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id              | integer |           | not null | nextval('core_artist_release_groups_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              |
 artist_id       | integer |           | not null |                                                        | plain   |              |
 releasegroup_id | integer |           | not null |                                                        | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "core_artist_release_groups_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "core_artist_release_grou_artist_id_releasegroup_i_c5191f18_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (artist_id, releasegroup_id)
    "core_artist_release_groups_artist_id_4dc95871" btree (artist_id)
    "core_artist_release_groups_releasegroup_id_cea5da71" btree (releasegroup_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "core_artist_release__releasegroup_id_cea5da71_fk_core_rele" FOREIGN KEY (releasegroup_id) REFERENCES core_releasegroup(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "core_artist_release_groups_artist_id_4dc95871_fk_core_artist_id" FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES core_artist(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Subscription schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.core_subscription (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    modified_date timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    last_notification_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    artist_id integer NOT NULL,
    profile_id integer NOT NULL,
    library_id character varying(512)
);
```

Indices:

```
 schemaname |     tablename     |                      indexname                       | tablespace |                                                                 indexdef
------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | core_subscription | core_subscription_pkey                               |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_subscription_pkey ON public.core_subscription USING btree (id)
 public     | core_subscription | core_subscription_profile_id_artist_id_a4d3d29b_uniq |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_subscription_profile_id_artist_id_a4d3d29b_uniq ON public.core_subscription USING btree (profile_id, artist_id)
 public     | core_subscription | core_subscription_artist_id_0b3ffc23                 |            | CREATE INDEX core_subscription_artist_id_0b3ffc23 ON public.core_subscription USING btree (artist_id)
 public     | core_subscription | core_subscription_profile_id_ee2db298                |            | CREATE INDEX core_subscription_profile_id_ee2db298 ON public.core_subscription USING btree (profile_id)
```

```sql
 schemaname |     tablename     |                   indexname                   | tablespace |                                                                indexdef
------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | core_releasegroup | core_releasegroup_applemusic_id_aec4a5cb_uniq |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_releasegroup_applemusic_id_aec4a5cb_uniq ON public.core_releasegroup USING btree (applemusic_id)
 public     | core_releasegroup | core_releasegroup_pkey                        |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX core_releasegroup_pkey ON public.core_releasegroup USING btree (id)
 public     | core_releasegroup | core_releasegroup_applemusic_id_aec4a5cb_like |            | CREATE INDEX core_releasegroup_applemusic_id_aec4a5cb_like ON public.core_releasegroup USING btree (applemusic_id varchar_pattern_ops)
 public     | core_releasegroup | core_releasegroup_release_date_03a267f7       |            | CREATE INDEX core_releasegroup_release_date_03a267f7 ON public.core_releasegroup USING btree (release_date)
 public     | core_releasegroup | core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d               |            | CREATE INDEX core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d ON public.core_releasegroup USING btree (type)
 public     | core_releasegroup | core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d_like          |            | CREATE INDEX core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d_like ON public.core_releasegroup USING btree (type varchar_pattern_ops)
```

<s>**Here's the PostgreSQL execution plan:** (**notice the estimates**)</s>

**See updated plan below, after running `ANALYZE;` on database.**

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=2437.52..10850.51 rows=4 width=495) (actual time=411.911..8619.311 rows=362 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=252537 read=29104
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2437.09..10578.84 rows=569 width=499) (actual time=372.265..8446.324 rows=36314 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=143252 read=29085
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on core_releasegroup  (cost=2436.66..4636.70 rows=567 width=495) (actual time=372.241..7707.466 rows=32679 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date) AND ((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[])))
               Heap Blocks: exact=29127
               Buffers: shared hit=10222 read=27872
               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2436.66..2436.66 rows=567 width=0) (actual time=366.750..366.750 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=15 read=8952
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on core_releasegroup_release_date_03a267f7  (cost=0.00..342.46 rows=16203 width=0) (actual time=8.834..8.834 rows=32679 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date))
                           Buffers: shared read=92
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d_like  (cost=0.00..2093.67 rows=113420 width=0) (actual time=355.071..355.071 rows=3240568 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[]))
                           Buffers: shared hit=15 read=8860
         ->  Index Scan using core_artist_release_groups_releasegroup_id_cea5da71 on core_artist_release_groups  (cost=0.43..10.46 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.018..0.020 rows=1 loops=32679)
               Index Cond: (releasegroup_id = core_releasegroup.id)
               Buffers: shared hit=133030 read=1213
   ->  Index Only Scan using core_subscription_profile_id_artist_id_a4d3d29b_uniq on core_subscription u0  (cost=0.43..0.48 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=36314)
         Index Cond: ((profile_id = 1) AND (artist_id = core_artist_release_groups.artist_id))
         Heap Fetches: 362
         Buffers: shared hit=109285 read=19
 Planning Time: 10.951 ms
 Execution Time: 8619.564 ms
```

Please note that the above is a stripped down version of the actual query I need. Because of its unbearable slowness, I've stripped down this query to a bare-minimum and reverted to doing some filtering and ordering of the returned objects in Python (which I know is usually slower). As you can see, it's still very slow.

After a while, probably because the memory/cache are populated, this query becomes much faster: (**see updated after running `ANALYZE`**)

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=2437.52..10850.51 rows=4 width=495) (actual time=306.337..612.232 rows=362 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=241776 read=39865 written=4
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2437.09..10578.84 rows=569 width=499) (actual time=305.216..546.749 rows=36314 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=132503 read=39834 written=4
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on core_releasegroup  (cost=2436.66..4636.70 rows=567 width=495) (actual time=305.195..437.375 rows=32679 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date) AND ((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[])))
               Heap Blocks: exact=29127
               Buffers: shared hit=16 read=38078 written=4
               ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2436.66..2436.66 rows=567 width=0) (actual time=298.382..298.382 rows=0 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=16 read=8951
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on core_releasegroup_release_date_03a267f7  (cost=0.00..342.46 rows=16203 width=0) (actual time=5.619..5.619 rows=32679 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date))
                           Buffers: shared read=92
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d_like  (cost=0.00..2093.67 rows=113420 width=0) (actual time=289.917..289.917 rows=3240568 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[]))
                           Buffers: shared hit=16 read=8859
         ->  Index Scan using core_artist_release_groups_releasegroup_id_cea5da71 on core_artist_release_groups  (cost=0.43..10.46 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=32679)
               Index Cond: (releasegroup_id = core_releasegroup.id)
               Buffers: shared hit=132487 read=1756
   ->  Index Only Scan using core_subscription_profile_id_artist_id_a4d3d29b_uniq on core_subscription u0  (cost=0.43..0.48 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=36314)
         Index Cond: ((profile_id = 1) AND (artist_id = core_artist_release_groups.artist_id))
         Heap Fetches: 362
         Buffers: shared hit=109273 read=31
 Planning Time: 1.088 ms
 Execution Time: 612.360 ms
```

This is still slow in SQL terms (I guess?), but much more acceptable. The problem is, even though this is a very common view in my web-app (an often executed query), it is still not kept around in RAM/cache, and so I see these huge response-time spikes too often.

**I've tried every combination of constructing those queries. Some remedy attempts:**

1. Remove the `core_releasegroup.type` filter altogether to inspect whether it's the culprit
2. Create a `DESC` index on `core_releasegroup.release_date`, because it's more common than just an `ASC` index.
3. A `DISTINCT ON(id)` clause.

The only thing that helps consistently is decreasing the timeframe from 1 month to 1 week.

My last attempt is to see whether the planner estimations are to blame here, and if they're fixable. If not, I'll start considering de-normalization.

Or is there something else I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

Ok, after a comment from [Gerard H. Pille](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/143823/gerard-h-pille), It appears that both my local copy of the database & my production database have never been analyzed. Here's the execution plan (still off) after running `ANALYZE;`: (notice the row estimate is still off, and query time is still pretty long)

```
 Gather  (cost=1697.69..43260.89 rows=69 width=424) (actual time=522.372..5147.785 rows=362 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=218811 read=81318
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=697.69..42253.99 rows=29 width=424) (actual time=993.252..5122.081 rows=121 loops=3)
         Buffers: shared hit=218811 read=81318
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=697.26..35407.52 rows=8819 width=4) (actual time=3.201..507.423 rows=23496 loops=3)
               Hash Cond: (core_artist_release_groups.artist_id = u0.artist_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=416 read=17749
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on core_artist_release_groups  (cost=0.00..31150.65 rows=1355965 width=8) (actual time=0.153..223.448 rows=1084772 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=2 read=17589
               ->  Hash  (cost=690.92..690.92 rows=507 width=4) (actual time=2.636..2.637 rows=1689 loops=3)
                     Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 76kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=315 read=155
                     ->  Index Scan using core_subscription_profile_id_ee2db298 on core_subscription u0  (cost=0.43..690.92 rows=507 width=4) (actual time=0.067..1.966 rows=1689 loops=3)
                           Index Cond: (profile_id = 1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=315 read=155
         ->  Index Scan using core_releasegroup_pkey on core_releasegroup  (cost=0.43..0.78 rows=1 width=424) (actual time=0.195..0.195 rows=0 loops=70489)
               Index Cond: (id = core_artist_release_groups.releasegroup_id)
               Filter: ((release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date) AND ((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[])))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
               Buffers: shared hit=218395 read=63569
 Planning Time: 4.796 ms
 Execution Time: 5147.966 ms
```

And after RAM/cache has been populated:

```sql
 Gather  (cost=1697.69..43260.89 rows=69 width=424) (actual time=103.916..745.476 rows=362 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=218972 read=81137
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=697.69..42253.99 rows=29 width=424) (actual time=134.936..730.317 rows=121 loops=3)
         Buffers: shared hit=218972 read=81137
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=697.26..35407.52 rows=8819 width=4) (actual time=2.027..441.156 rows=23496 loops=3)
               Hash Cond: (core_artist_release_groups.artist_id = u0.artist_id)
               Buffers: shared hit=556 read=17589
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on core_artist_release_groups  (cost=0.00..31150.65 rows=1355965 width=8) (actual time=0.042..195.811 rows=1084772 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=3 read=17588
               ->  Hash  (cost=690.92..690.92 rows=507 width=4) (actual time=1.823..1.823 rows=1689 loops=3)
                     Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 76kB
                     Buffers: shared hit=469 read=1
                     ->  Index Scan using core_subscription_profile_id_ee2db298 on core_subscription u0  (cost=0.43..690.92 rows=507 width=4) (actual time=0.058..1.283 rows=1689 loops=3)
                           Index Cond: (profile_id = 1)
                           Buffers: shared hit=469 read=1
         ->  Index Scan using core_releasegroup_pkey on core_releasegroup  (cost=0.43..0.78 rows=1 width=424) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=70489)
               Index Cond: (id = core_artist_release_groups.releasegroup_id)
               Filter: ((release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date) AND ((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[])))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
               Buffers: shared hit=218416 read=63548
 Planning Time: 1.077 ms
 Execution Time: 745.604 ms
```

Still quite slow, and it seems like the indices aren't being used?

Explain after adding composite_index `release_date DESC, type`, and running `VACUUM(ANALYZE)`:

```sql
 Nested Loop  (cost=1.29..18720.56 rows=46 width=425) (actual time=0.990..423.496 rows=362 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=223769 read=63437 written=4
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..2732.78 rows=20594 width=4) (actual time=0.048..30.681 rows=70489 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared hit=4245 read=1005
         ->  Index Only Scan using core_subscription_profile_id_artist_id_a4d3d29b_uniq on core_subscription u0  (cost=0.43..17.14 rows=498 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.549 rows=1689 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (profile_id = 1)
               Heap Fetches: 0
               Buffers: shared hit=5 read=3
         ->  Index Only Scan using core_artist_release_grou_artist_id_releasegroup_i_c5191f18_uniq on core_artist_release_groups  (cost=0.43..5.04 rows=41 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.011 rows=42 loops=1689)
               Index Cond: (artist_id = u0.artist_id)
               Heap Fetches: 0
               Buffers: shared hit=4240 read=1002
   ->  Index Scan using core_releasegroup_pkey on core_releasegroup  (cost=0.43..0.78 rows=1 width=425) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=70489)
         Index Cond: (id = core_artist_release_groups.releasegroup_id)
         Filter: ((release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date) AND ((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[])))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1
         Buffers: shared hit=219524 read=62432 written=4
 Planning Time: 0.999 ms
 Execution Time: 423.600 ms
```

Should I be satisfied with this result? or there room for more improvement? I've applied `VACUUM(ANALYZE)` to the production database as well and there's some improvement but this is still slower than I'd like.

Comment: The planner seriously underestimates the number of rows returned between the two dates from core_releasegroup.  When was this table last analyzed?

Comment: I think it is done weekly by Heroku. It’s their managed PostgreSQL plan - it gets maintained every week. How can I check that explicitly?

Comment: SELECT schemaname, relname, last_analyze FROM pg_stat_all_tables WHERE relname = 'core_releasegroup'  ?

Comment: you're missing a couple of tables in your schema.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I know, which additional ones would you like to see? how can I print the **current** schema, not my history long of changes (because it's rather long)

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - This is so weird. Both my local copy and my Heroku instance show that `core_releasegroup` has NEVER been analyzed. Doesn't VACUUMing also analyze?

Comment: Will post my post-`ANALYZE` results shortly.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I've updated my results post-ANALYZE.

Comment: It would help to have a description of all the tables used in the selection, also their indices.

Comment: Vacuum doesn't analyze, says https://www.dbrnd.com/2015/11/postgresql-short-note-on-vacuum-vacuum-full-and-analyze/, but you can "vacuum analyze".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I’ve shared my results post vacuum and analyze. Still a bit slow to my liking...will post all schemas in a bit.

Comment: did you analyze all three tables?

Comment: I’ve analyzed the whole database.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - I've updated all 3 schemas + indexes.

Comment: core_artist_release_groups?

Comment: "how can I print the current schema" : pg_dump ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add an index on core_releasegroup(type,release_date)
and try this:

```
SELECT
   "core_releasegroup"."id",
   "core_releasegroup"."title",
   "core_releasegroup"."type",
   "core_releasegroup"."release_date",
   "core_releasegroup"."applemusic_id",
   "core_releasegroup"."applemusic_image",
   "core_releasegroup"."geo_apple_music_link",
   "core_releasegroup"."amazon_aff_link",
   "core_releasegroup"."is_explicit",
   "core_releasegroup"."spotify_id",
   "core_releasegroup"."spotify_link"
  FROM "core_releasegroup"
  where exists (select null from
                 "core_artist_release_groups" arg,
                 "core_subscription" U0
                 WHERE U0."profile_id" + 0 = 1
                   and U0."artist_id" = arg."artist_id" + 0
                   and arg."releasegroup_id" = "core_releasegroup"."id" + 0
               )
    AND "core_releasegroup"."type" IN
          ('Album', 'Single', 'EP', 'Live', 'Compilation', 'Remix', 'Other') 
    AND "core_releasegroup"."release_date"
           BETWEEN '2020-08-20'::date AND '2020-10-20'::date;
```

?

Explain I'd like him to use (I don't have all the indices in the schema I built, moreover: all tables are empty).

```
 Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=11.90..59.08 rows=1 width=3699)
   Join Filter: (core_releasegroup.id = arg.releasegroup_id)
   ->  Index Scan using rg_rgrd on core_releasegroup  (cost=0.14..9.04 rows=1 width=3699)
         Index Cond: (((type)::text = ANY ('{Album,Single,EP,Live,Compilation,Remix,Other}'::text[])) AND (release_date >= '2020-08-20'::date) AND (release_date <= '2020-10-20'::date))
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.76..49.91 rows=10 width=4)
         Hash Cond: (arg.artist_id = u0.artist_id)
         ->  Seq Scan on core_artist_release_groups arg  (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=8)
         ->  Hash  (cost=11.75..11.75 rows=1 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on core_subscription u0  (cost=0.00..11.75 rows=1 width=4)
                     Filter: (profile_id = 1)
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Most queries (though not a huge majority) will order by desc release_date. I’ve only omitted this here because I was simplifying the query as much as I can. Also, should it be in the order you specified?

Comment: I always prefer solving real problems, rather than someone's fantasies.  Yes, if you would be so kind.  I don't know your timezone, but I'm calling it quits for today.  Goeie nacht en slaap wel!

Comment: Fair enough. I'll mark your answer as you've already helped solved the huge issue of having a completely non-analyzed database. Appreciate the help!

Comment: FWIW, query-time stays around .5 seconds. The above query is actually slower.

Comment: core_artist_release_groups descr & indices please, it's the missing link. Can I have the explain of my query?

Comment: I've added the schema. Here's the execution plan for the above query (had to remove a straying `)` at then end): https://pastebin.pl/view/fec3a6ec

Comment: That was to see if you were paying attention.

Comment: He's not using the index I asked you to create.  I've added the explain plan I'd like him to use.

Comment: The index is there.

Comment: Here's the link to the updated schema: https://pastebin.pl/view/2bd0e0d3

Comment: Can you drop the following ?  He can use the new ones when needed.       "core_releasegroup_release_date_03a267f7" btree (release_date)
    "core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d" btree (type)
    "core_releasegroup_type_58b6243d_like" btree (type varchar_pattern_ops)

Comment: output after removing those indexes and running analyze: https://pastebin.pl/view/5c0973c2

Comment: One more try, I've added a couple of "+ 0", a trick as old as SQL.

Comment: plan did change, timing not so: https://pastebin.pl/view/d098a8df

Comment: He's sure is stubborn, keeps attacking from the wrong side.   "WHERE U0."profile_id" + 0 = 1"

Comment: I don't know what we're even trying at the moment, but here's the output: https://pastebin.pl/view/907d3a16

Comment: Trying to make it run faster?  Seems I can't do any better than half a second.  How long does this query take when the cache is fresh?

Comment: Around 10 seconds. It would be great if it didn’t get out of the cache so often. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I managed to make it twice as bad?  Great help.  The data you're working with isn't coming from a publc database, I suppose?